# How do I sort a dropdown list alphabetically in a .jsp file?

Tags: sorting, jsp

```
<form:select path="workspace" placeholder="Workspace">
    <c:forEach var="workspace" items="${workspaces}">
        <form:option value="${workspace.wsShortName}" label="${workspace.objectName}" />    
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

This displays a list of all the workspaces. However, I can't seem to find a way to sort them alphabetically. It seems that they are sorted by creation date/time at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort it by alphabetical order before you pass the parameter `workspaces` from back end to the front end.

For example, the end of the query sql of database statement plus the `order by name`